# What happens to CPU when WAITFOR statement is executed in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a [WAITFOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) statement in SQL Server. I want to know what exactly happens with respect to CPU and thread on SQL Server when this statement is executed. Does it use CPU cycles while waiting for the time or the thread goes into suspended mode?

Comment: SQL Server uses cooperative scheduling. The task will move from running to suspended and be put on a queue waiting for timer events, the worker thread will enter an infinite wait and cannot be scheduled on the CPU other running tasks will check this queue when they come off the scheduler and put the task back to runnable once the wait has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

While executing the WAITFOR statement, the transaction is running and no other requests can run under the same transaction.

Each WAITFOR statement has a thread associated with it. If many WAITFOR statements are specified on the same server, many threads can be tied up waiting for these statements to run. SQL Server monitors the number of threads associated with WAITFOR statements, and randomly selects some of these threads to exit if the server starts to experience thread starvation. Including WAITFOR will slow the completion of the SQL Server process and can result in a timeout message in the application. If necessary, adjust the timeout setting for the connection at the application level.

taken from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx)